# Trying to find the max occurrences in dataset based on a group by

Tags: oracle

I have a table like this:

```
ID   group_name 
=============
9   Yellow
9   Yellow
3   Yellow
1   Red
2   Red
5   Red
5   Red
99  Green
99  Green
```

I would like the output to be the most frequent ID within each group_name, in this example:

```
9  Yellow
5  Red
99 Green
```

in the case of green, there was only one possible choice, but still want just 1 row returned, per group_name

any ideas?  I have seen other attempts at this using dense_rank and limit ... but I couldn't get the output quite right.

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> any ideas? I have seen other attempts at this using `dense_rank` and
>   `limit` ... but I couldn't get the output quite right.

Huh?  Why are people using `dense_rank`?  In Statistics, what you seek is called [MODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(statistics)).  Oracle has an aggregate called [STATS_MODE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm) to find `mode`.  You should use that.  (Make sure you read the document for information about "what happens if there are 2 IDs that fit the criteria?" )

Example SQL:

```
with data as (
  select 9 id,  'Yellow' group_name from dual union all
  select 9   ,'Yellow' group_name from dual union all
  select 3   ,'Yellow' group_name from dual union all
  select 1   ,'Red' group_name from dual union all
  select 2   ,'Red' group_name from dual union all
  select 5   ,'Red' group_name from dual union all
  select 5   ,'Red' group_name from dual union all
  select 99  ,'Green' group_name from dual union all
  select 99  ,'Green' group_name from dual 
)
select stats_mode( id ) as id
      ,group_name
from data
group by group_name
order by group_name;
```

Results:

```
ID  GROUP_NAME
--  ----------
99  Green
5   Red
9   Yellow
```

Comment: Wow - that definitely worked for me!  I was struggling with that. I have to read up on "stats_mode" - never used it before.  Thank you very much!

Comment: If you are not aware that Oracle can solve `y = m * x + b` via `REGR_*`, you should read the fine manual and review what aggregate/analytic functions are built in. ;)  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions003.htm#SQLRF20035